# Script Function Could not be found when assigned to a button

Tags: google-apps-script, button, google-sheets

I have buttons on a form which are configured to run a script.  Each button is unique to an individual script.  The scripts run successfully in Script Editor yet they appear as not found when clicking on any of the buttons.

The scripts below seem to be functional.  I am uncertain what I need to do to resolve why when assigned to a button they are not found.

```
    function myFunction() {
// Clear form
function ClearCell() {
  var ss        =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS     =ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet

  var rangesToClear = ["b7","d7","f7","h7","b9","d9","f9","h9","b12"];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) {
    formS.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Input Values
  function SubmitData() {
    var ss      =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS   =ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet
    var dataS   =ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log"); //Data Sheet
    
    
    var values = [[formS.getRange("b7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("d7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("f7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("h7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("b9").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("d9").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("f9").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("h9").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("b12").getValue()]];
    dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9).setValues(values);
    ClearCell();
  }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Search Records
  var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
  function Search(){
    var ss      =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS   =ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet  

  var str     =formS.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<values.length;i++){
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] ==str){
      
    formS.getRange("b7").setValue(row[0]),
    formS.getRange("d7").setValue(row[1]),
    formS.getRange("f7").setValue(row[2]),
    formS.getRange("h7").setValue(row[3]),
    formS.getRange("b9").setValue(row[4]),
    formS.getRange("d9").setValue(row[5]),
    formS.getRange("f9").setValue(row[6]),
    formS.getRange("h9").setValue(row[7]),
    formS.getRange("b12").setValue(row[8]);  
      
    } }}
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //Update Data 
  function UpdateData(){
    var ss      =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS   =ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet
    var dataS   =ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log"); //Data Sheet   
    
    var str    =formS.getRange("B4").getValue();
    var values = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log").getDataRange().getValues();    
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str){
      var  INT_R = i+1
      
    var values1 = [[formS.getRange("b7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("d7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("f7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("h7").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("b9").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("d9").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("f9").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("h9").getValue(),
                   formS.getRange("b12").getValue()]];
      dataS.getRange(INT_R,1,1,9).setValues(values1);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('  "Data Updated  " ');
      ClearCell();  
    } } }
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Delete Data
  function Delete() {
    var ss      =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS   =ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet
    var dataS   =ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log"); //Data Sheet  

var ui = spreadsheetApp.get.Ui();
var response = ui.alert('Delete ?',ui.ButtonSet.Yes_No);

//Process the user's response.
    if (response == ui.Button.Yes) {
      
  var str = formS.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i <values.length; i++) {
  var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
      var INT_R = i+1
      
      dataS.deleteRow(INT_R) ;
      ClearCell();
    }}} }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets can't find your functions because it is enclosed with `myFunction()`. This makes `myFunction()` the only visible function to Google Sheets. To fix that, just remove the `myFunction(){}` that encloses other functions.

Your code should look like this:

```
// Clear form
function ClearCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet

  var rangesToClear = ["b7", "d7", "f7", "h7", "b9", "d9", "f9", "h9", "b12"];
  for (var i = 0; i < rangesToClear.length; i++) {
    formS.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Input Values
function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log"); //Data Sheet


  var values = [
    [formS.getRange("b7").getValue(),
      formS.getRange("d7").getValue(),
      formS.getRange("f7").getValue(),
      formS.getRange("h7").getValue(),
      formS.getRange("b9").getValue(),
      formS.getRange("d9").getValue(),
      formS.getRange("f9").getValue(),
      formS.getRange("h9").getValue(),
      formS.getRange("b12").getValue()
    ]
  ];
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 9).setValues(values);
  ClearCell();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Search Records
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;

function Search() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet  

  var str = formS.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {

      formS.getRange("b7").setValue(row[0]),
        formS.getRange("d7").setValue(row[1]),
        formS.getRange("f7").setValue(row[2]),
        formS.getRange("h7").setValue(row[3]),
        formS.getRange("b9").setValue(row[4]),
        formS.getRange("d9").setValue(row[5]),
        formS.getRange("f9").setValue(row[6]),
        formS.getRange("h9").setValue(row[7]),
        formS.getRange("b12").setValue(row[8]);

    }
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Update Data 
function UpdateData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log"); //Data Sheet   

  var str = formS.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
      var INT_R = i + 1

      var values1 = [
        [formS.getRange("b7").getValue(),
          formS.getRange("d7").getValue(),
          formS.getRange("f7").getValue(),
          formS.getRange("h7").getValue(),
          formS.getRange("b9").getValue(),
          formS.getRange("d9").getValue(),
          formS.getRange("f9").getValue(),
          formS.getRange("h9").getValue(),
          formS.getRange("b12").getValue()
        ]
      ];
      dataS.getRange(INT_R, 1, 1, 9).setValues(values1);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('  "Data Updated  " ');
      ClearCell();
    }
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Delete Data
function Delete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log"); //Data Sheet  

  var ui = spreadsheetApp.get.Ui();
  var response = ui.alert('Delete ?', ui.ButtonSet.Yes_No);

  //Process the user's response.
  if (response == ui.Button.Yes) {

    var str = formS.getRange("B4").getValue();
    var values = ss.getSheetByName("Traffic Discrepancy Log").getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var row = values[i];
      if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
        var INT_R = i + 1

        dataS.deleteRow(INT_R);
        ClearCell();
      }
    }
  }
}
```